# SQL Query need to finish within 4sec

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

Here is the query actual [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyfOkCIZP)

and the query is below

```
SELECT MemberId
    ,MemberCardId
    ,FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,STATE
    ,City
    ,Gender
    ,MemberAddress1
    ,ZipCode
    ,NewToHuamana
    ,Contract
    ,PhoneNumber
    ,CovidCohort
    ,AttributedStatus
    ,TotalGaps
    ,CloseGap
    ,OpenGaps
    ,RowNum
INTO #tbasic
FROM (
    SELECT a.MemberId
        ,MemberCardId
        ,FirstName
        ,LastName
        ,STATE
        ,City
        ,Gender
        ,MemberAddress1
        ,ZipCode
        ,NewToHuamana
        ,Contract
        ,PhoneNumber
        ,CovidCohort
        ,AttributedStatus
        ,a.TotalGap AS TotalGaps
        ,a.CloseGap
        ,a.TotalGap - a.CloseGap AS OpenGaps
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY a.id
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM [test_MBasic] a
    WHERE (
            @isOpen IS NULL
            OR a.HasOpenGap = @isOpen
            )
        AND (
            @isNewHumana IS NULL
            OR @isNewHumana = a.NewToHuamana
            )
        AND (
            @attributeStatus IS NULL
            OR @attributeStatus = a.AttributedStatus
            )
        AND (
            @regionCode IS NULL
            OR @regionCode = a.RegionCode
            )
        AND (
            @contract IS NULL
            OR @contract = a.Contract
            )
        AND (
            @state IS NULL
            OR @state = a.STATE
            )
        AND (
            @county IS NULL
            OR @county = a.County
            )
        AND (
            @nonCompliantMeasureLastYear IS NULL
            OR @nonCompliantMeasureLastYear = a.NotCompliant_PreviousYear
            )
    ) A
OPTION (RECOMPILE)

SELECT MemberId
    ,MemberCardId
    ,FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,STATE
    ,City
    ,Gender
    ,MemberAddress1
    ,ZipCode
    ,NewToHuamana
    ,Contract
    ,PhoneNumber
    ,CovidCohort
    ,AttributedStatus
    ,TotalGaps
    ,CloseGap
    ,OpenGaps
FROM #tbasic A
WHERE A.RowNum > (@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize
    AND A.RowNum <= @pageNumber * @pageSize
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

I used **recompile** to ignore parameter sniffing and temp table for avoiding pagination slow. this query takes 8sec in times of @isOpen parameter. I need to speed up more like within 4 to 5sec it will show 20rows when i will use @isOpen parameter.

Any one have any suggestion how can i achieve this to finish within 4sec.

Comment: Have you considerd using [Offset and Fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) to implement paging, instead of rownumber and temp tables.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts that is dangerous slow and yes i used that one also

Comment: How is the performance when you put the pagination where on your subquery, instead of using a temp table? IMO most of the time will be spent due the amount of rows (2.3 million) Have you also tried with maxdop 1 ?

Comment: Offset and Fetch with proper indexing should do the trick. Indexing really depends on how your data looks.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts yes I tried that as well

Answer (score 0):

According to your execution plan, the time is consuming on the temp table inserting operation.

[image]

So you need a faster temp table or tempdb configuration.
[Improving temp table and table variable performance using memory optimization](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/improving-temp-table-and-table-variable-performance-using-memory/ba-p/384697)

Another solution might be avoiding using a temp table but [**test_MBasic**] has a columnstore index and the query performance might be tested.
[Can ColumnStore Help Pagination Workloads?](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/columnstore-pagination)

Comment: deletes takes much time in improving tmp process that you reffered